# loop data inside an array

Tags: php, yii2

how can i store the values inside a loop in array and return as JSON in yii2.

I have problem with this code:

```
$start = date("Y/m/d");
            $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
            $end = date('Y/m/d', strtotime(sprintf("+%d months", $loanMonths)));
            $periods = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($start), $interval, new DateTime($end));
            $array = array();
            foreach($periods as $period){
                print_r(date('Y-F', strtotime($period->format('Y-m')))); echo "<br>";
            }
            \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return $period;
```

Comment: `$array[] = $value`

Comment: Note you might have issues with using 1 month as the interval. See [example 3](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need

```
 $array = array();
 foreach($periods as $period){
    $array []= date('Y-F', strtotime($period->format('Y-m')));
 }

 $response = Yii::$app->response;
 $response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
 $response->data = $array;

 return $response;
```